# Consulta SQL - Meter dos datos en una "Declare table"

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo 3 tablas que tengo que eliminar datos, pero tengo un problema.

tengo esta consulta hecha

```
DELETE FROM dbo.SalidaVTP  
WHERE SalidaVTP.id IN  
    (SELECT Solicitud.id FROM dbo.Solicitud WHERE Solicitud.FechaCreacion > @DATE);
```

Como puedo guardar los datos que he eliminado? Es decir de la tabla `SalidaVTP`  hay dos datos que me interesan el `ID` borrado y `ReabastecidaId` son dos datos que se incluyen en `salidaVTP`, pero me interesan saber los que borro. No los que quedan.

Como puedo hacer para sacar este dato?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar la clausula [`OUTPUT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) junto al `DELETE` para salvar los datos que te interesan:

```
CREATE TABLE #Deleted (
     ID              INT,
     ReabastecidaId  INT
)

DELETE FROM dbo.SalidaVTP 
       OUTPUT DELETED.ID, DELETED.ReabastecidaId INTO #Deleted  
       WHERE SalidaVTP.id IN (SELECT Solicitud.id 
                                     FROM dbo.Solicitud 
                                     WHERE Solicitud.FechaCreacion > @DATE);

SELECT * 
       FROM #Deleted
```

Answer (score 2):

Hay diferentes opciones, la primera sería crear un `TRIGGER` de borrado. En cualquier caso necesitas una tabla donde almacenar los datos eliminados.

```
CREATE TABLE Borrados (ID int, ReabastecidaId int)

CREATE TRIGGER TRG_DEL_SalidaVTP
ON dbo.SalidaVTP  
AFTER DELETE   
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Borrados(ID, ReabastecidaId)
    SELECT
        d.ID, d.ReabastecidaId
    FROM
        deleted d
END
```

Cuando se eliminen datos en la tabla `SalidaVTP` guardará en la tabla `Borrados` los elementos eliminados de forma automática.

Otra opción es hacerlo manualmente, antes del borrado

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO Borrados (ID, ReabastecidaId )
SELECT ID, ReabastecidaId 
FROM dbo.SalidaVTP  WHERE SalidaVTP.id IN  (SELECT Solicitud.id FROM dbo.Solicitud WHERE Solicitud.FechaCreacion > @DATE)

DELETE FROM dbo.SalidaVTP  WHERE SalidaVTP.id IN  (SELECT Solicitud.id FROM dbo.Solicitud WHERE Solicitud.FechaCreacion > @DATE)

COMMIT;
```